# Group arrays based on similar values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with this structure:

```
<?php
$grades = array(
        'Grade 1'  => array(
            'title'   => 'Grade 1 Class',
            'students' => 5,
            'teacher' => 'Smith',
        ),
        'Grade 2' => array(
            'title'   => 'Grade 2 Class',
            'students' => 5,
            'teacher' => 'Smith',
        ),
        'Grade 3' => array(
            'title'   =>'Grade 3 Class',
            'students' => 5,
            'teacher' => 'John',
        )
    );
```

where I want to group them based on certain attributes. For example to group all grades which have same number of students would be :

```
Grade 1 Class - Grade 3 Class     5
```

I got through the array like this:

```
foreach ($grades as $key => $value) {
   $return[$value['students']][] = $value['title'];
}

foreach ($return as $key => $value) {
   echo implode(' - ', $value)."\t\t".$key;
}
// output is 
// Grade 1 Class - Grade 2 Class - Grade 3 Class      5
```

but the above code outputs the middle grade as well, how can I only output the first and last elements to get the desired output assuming we may not know where the similar values occurs?

For example, for [this array](http://pastebin.com/raw/CXuB90HU) this is the desired output:

```
Grade 1 Class - Grade 2 Class     5
Grade 3 Class - Grade 6 Class     8
Grade 7 Class                     9 
Grade 8 Class - Grade 9 Class     4
```

Comment: Can you build an array that you want outputted too please?

Comment: @Pachonk I don't want to create another array after the initial array, I just want to output them in groups.

Comment: Ahh, okay I get it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in question, you need only first and last element. First you need to group array according to student id and than print first and last element. I have update your code as  -

```
$grades = array(
    'Grade 1'  => array(
        'title'   => 'Grade 1 Class',
        'students' => 5,
        'teacher' => 'Smith',
    ),
    'Grade 2' => array(
        'title'   => 'Grade 2 Class',
        'students' => 5,
        'teacher' => 'Smith',
    ),
    'Grade 3' => array(
        'title'   =>'Grade 3 Class',
        'students' => 8,
        'teacher' => 'John',
    ),
    'Grade 4' => array(
        'title'   =>'Grade 4 Class',
        'students' => 8,
        'teacher' => 'John',
    ),
    'Grade 5' => array(
        'title'   =>'Grade 5 Class',
        'students' => 8,
        'teacher' => 'John',
    ),
    'Grade 6' => array(
        'title'   =>'Grade 6 Class',
        'students' => 8,
        'teacher' => 'John',
    ),
    'Grade 7' => array(
        'title'   =>'Grade 7 Class',
        'students' => 9,
        'teacher' => 'John',
    ),
    'Grade 8' => array(
        'title'   =>'Grade 8 Class',
        'students' => 4,
        'teacher' => 'John',
    ),
);

$newArray = array();
$keyIndex = 0;
$s = null;
foreach ($grades as $key => $value) {
    if($s != $value['students']){
        $keyIndex++;
    }
    $newArray[$keyIndex][] = $value;
    $s = $value['students'];
}

foreach ($newArray as $student => $data) {
    $gradeFirst =  key($data);
    // Check there are multiple grade or single grade
    if(count($data) > 1){
        $lastGrade = end($data);
        echo $data[$gradeFirst]['title'].' - '.$lastGrade['title'] .' '. $lastGrade['students'];
    }
    else{
        echo $data[$gradeFirst]['title'] .' '. $data[$gradeFirst]['students'];
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

First loop group all element according to student. Second Loop print output on screen. If condition is added in second loop if for check that there is single grade or multiple grade for a student.

It return output as

```
Grade 1 Class - Grade 2 Class 5
Grade 3 Class - Grade 6 Class 8
Grade 7 Class 9
Grade 8 Class 4
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, there is a bug in your code, for example if you run it using [this array](http://pastebin.com/raw/TzJCVstA) which is from the possible scenarios, you get a wrong output

Comment: Thanks for report bug. I have fixed the bug.

Comment: I think I found another bug, [checkout this example](http://pastebin.com/raw/ppjUYjcY) and you can see the result is incorrect

Comment: @RainMan i have do code for show first and last grade of a student which is working. You expectation is that you need to show another grade to if there is gap between grade. Don't worry i am updating code accordingly.

Comment: I have updated the code. @RainMan please check. Let me know for further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
<?php

$grades = array(
        'Grade 1'  => array(
            'title'   => 'Grade 1 Class',
            'students' => 5,
            'teacher' => 'Smith',
        ),
        'Grade 2' => array(
            'title'   => 'Grade 2 Class',
            'students' => 5,
            'teacher' => 'Smith',
        ),
        'Grade 3' => array(
            'title'   =>'Grade 3 Class',
            'students' => 8,
            'teacher' => 'John',
        ),
        'Grade 4' => array(
            'title'   =>'Grade 4 Class',
            'students' => 5,
            'teacher' => 'Tina',
        )
    );


foreach ( $grades as $outer_k => $outer_v ) {
    // hold current $outer_k and start looping through $grades agaain, doing
    // comparison
    foreach ( $grades as $inner_k => $inner_v ) {
        // check inner_k is not comparing itself to itself
        if ( $inner_k !== $outer_k ) {
            if ( $inner_v['students'] === $outer_v['students'] ) {
                $matches[] = $inner_v['title'];
                $num_students = $inner_v['students'];
            }
        }
    }
}

sort($matches);
$result = array_unique($matches);
$result = array_values($result);

$length = count($result) - 1;
echo $result[0] . " - " . $result[$length] . "\t\t{$num_students}\n";
```

produces this output:

```
Grade 1 Class - Grade 4 Class           5
```

Comment: thanks for answer, this does not output all possible values. I will modify the question to reflect what the desired output is.