# How to create sub associative array?

Tags: php

I am learning associative arrays. This is what I am doing:

```
array_push( $classe ,array(
  'year'=>$annoClasse,
  'section'=>$sezione,
  'student'=>$member->first_name." ".$member->last_name)
);
```

That creates:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'year' => 'Secondo',
    'section' => 'd',
    'student' => 'Stephany Johnson',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'year' => 'Secondo',
    'section' => 'd',
    'student' => 'Sandra White',
  ),
)
```

How would I create something like this? Basically to have each separate property for the student.

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'year' => 'Second',
    'section' => 'd',
    'student' (
      'name' => 'Stephany',
      'surname' => 'Johnson'
    )
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'year' => 'Second',
    'section' => 'd',
    'student' (
      'name' => 'Sandra',
      'surname' => 'White'
     ),
   )
 )
```

And how would I then echo the student only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished with the following code:

```
array_push( $classe ,array(
                   'year'=>$annoClasse,
                   'section'=>$sezione,
                   'student'=>array(
                       'name'=>$member->first_name,
                       'surname'=>$member->last_name
                   )
);
```

Then to echo only the student:

```
foreach ($classe as $c) {
    echo $c['student']['name'] . " " . $c['student']['surname'] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: thanks, I was almost there then! It is missing one ) tho, accepting

Comment: @rob.m I would also suggest to create arrays using `[` and `]` instead of `array(` and `)`, it looks much neater in my opinion :) E.g. `$array = ['key' => 'value'];`

Comment: what if we have the same values for "year" and "section"? if we loop we'd get twice the result but what if we only want to echo them once following all the students? Like: year 2020 > student sandra and stephany?

Comment: I guess echo $c['year'][0]?

Comment: @rob.m `echo $c['year'][0]` would present an error because `$c['year']` is a string. You would need to loop through `$classe`, and build a new array using the years as the key.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like that :

```
array_push( $classe ,array('year'=>$annoClasse, 'section'=>$sezione, 'student' => array('name' => $student_name, 'surname' => $student_surname)));
```

use foreach to loop the array and print the values you want :

```
foreach ($classe as $key => $value) {
    echo $value['student']['name']; // or echo $value['student']['surname']; etc..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign anything to the array key, it can be a bool, integer, string, or array. In your case just assign a new array to the student key.

```
array_push( $classe, array(
   'year'    => $annoClasse,
   'section' => $sezione,
   'student' => array(
       'name' => $member->first_name,
       'surname' => $member->last_name
   )
));
```

Comment: Thanks, had that answer and it correct like yours. One question tho, since both year and section might be the same, let's say "year 2020" and "section H" and then again "year 2020" and "section H", how would you echo only 1 when looping?

Comment: So you mean how you can have many students inside a year and section?

Comment: yes exactly, like grouping them by a class defined by year and section

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40814103/group-arrays-based-on-similar-values-in-php